Playing sound on a Device that uses the microphone input as sound input
So, I've got a device that records audio only using the microphone input and plays some other audio with the speaker output.
I know it's through NAudio, But i can't find any documentation of how to do this.
And yes, i could do some  external program but the plan is to do it across multiple computers and devices.

Why don't you have a look here: NAudio


I know it's through NAudio, But i can't find any documentation of how to do this.

NAudio has a lot of tutorial By referring to How to record Wave file i have created the following code

Record() to start recording and save the record in file located at ~/desktop/NAudio/recorded.wav
Stop()  to end Recording

using NAudio.Wave;
//----
WaveFileWriter writer = null;

WaveInEvent waveIn = null;

string FilePath
{
    get
    {
        var outputFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "NAudio");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
        var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFolder, "recorded.wav");
        return outputFilePath;
    }
}

public void Record()
{
    waveIn = new WaveInEvent();
    writer = new WaveFileWriter(FilePath, waveIn.WaveFormat);
    waveIn.StartRecording();
    IsRecording = true;
    
    waveIn.DataAvailable += WaveIn_DataAvailable;
    waveIn.RecordingStopped += WaveIn_RecordingStopped;
}

public void Stop()
{
    waveIn?.StopRecording();
    IsRecording = false;
}

private void WaveIn_DataAvailable(object? sender, WaveInEventArgs a)
{
    writer.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
    if (writer.Position > waveIn.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 30)
    {
        waveIn.StopRecording();
    }
}

private void WaveIn_RecordingStopped(object? sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    writer?.Dispose();
    writer = null;
    IsRecording = false;
}

And to play the sound you can use the following code.

Play() play the previously recorded wave file ~/desktop/NAudio/recorded.wav.
StopPlay() stop playing

WaveFileReader? fileReader = null;
 
WaveOutEvent? waveOut = null;
public void Play()
{
    waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
    fileReader = new WaveFileReader(FilePath);
    waveOut.Init(fileReader);
    waveOut.Play();
    IsPlay = true;
    waveOut.PlaybackStopped += WaveOut_PlaybackStopped;
}
 
public void StopPlay()
{
    waveOut?.Stop();
    IsPlay = false;
}
private void WaveOut_PlaybackStopped(object? sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    IsRecording = false;
    fileReader?.Dispose();
}

you can combine all this code in a single complete class to work as ViewModel class as following (I use community toolkit to make it easy)
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.IO;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(RecordCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(StopCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(PlayCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(StopPlayCommand))]
    bool isRecording = false;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(RecordCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(StopCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(PlayCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(StopPlayCommand))]
    bool isPlay = false;

    bool CanPlay => !IsPlay && !IsRecording;
    bool CanRecording => !IsRecording && !IsPlay;

    WaveFileWriter? writer = null;
    WaveFileReader? fileReader = null;

    WaveInEvent? waveIn = null;
    WaveOutEvent? waveOut = null;

    string FilePath
    {
        get
        {
            var outputFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "NAudio");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFolder);
            var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFolder, "recorded.wav");
            return outputFilePath;
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanPlay))]
    public void Play()
    {
        waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
        fileReader = new WaveFileReader(FilePath);
        waveOut.Init(fileReader);
        waveOut.Play();
        IsPlay = true;
        waveOut.PlaybackStopped += WaveOut_PlaybackStopped;
    }

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(IsPlay))]
    public void StopPlay()
    {
        waveOut?.Stop();
        IsPlay = false;
    }

    private void WaveOut_PlaybackStopped(object? sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsRecording = false;
        fileReader?.Dispose();
    }

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanRecording))]
    public void Record()
    {
        waveIn = new WaveInEvent();

        writer = new WaveFileWriter(FilePath, waveIn.WaveFormat);
        waveIn.StartRecording();
        IsRecording = true;

        waveIn.DataAvailable += WaveIn_DataAvailable;
        waveIn.RecordingStopped += WaveIn_RecordingStopped;

    }

    private void WaveIn_RecordingStopped(object? sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        writer?.Dispose();
        writer = null;
        IsRecording = false;
    }

    private void WaveIn_DataAvailable(object? sender, WaveInEventArgs a)
    {
        writer?.Write(a.Buffer, 0, a.BytesRecorded);
        if (writer?.Position > waveIn?.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 30)
        {
            waveIn?.StopRecording();
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(IsRecording))]
    public void Stop()
    {
        waveIn?.StopRecording();
        IsRecording = false;
    }
}

Finally, you can build the UI with any framework you like and bind it to this class, for example you can use  avalonia ui framework to create a cross-platform UI.the UI code will be as following
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">     
  <Button Content="Record" Command="{Binding RecordCommand}"/>
  <Button Content="Stop" Command="{Binding StopCommand}"/>
  <Button Content="Play" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}"/>
  <Button Content="Stop Playing" Command="{Binding StopPlayCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>

